# Best way to generate ASCII tree visualization of a directory with long file paths?

Tags: windows-10, path, tree-view

I've enabled the `Enable Win32 long paths` template in the Local Group Policy Editor. I have a directory with several nested directories that have long file path names.

I'm trying to generate an ASCII tree using the Windows `tree /A` command. It does give output, though it actually omits all directories that have a file path length greater than 260 characters. Is there some way to generate these that support long file paths?

Comment: I would give WSL a try. May be the Linux utils can handle such paths better.

Comment: Yeah, ran `tree` on Ubuntu WSL in the mounted drives and got all that I needed. Replaced some characters with ASCII ones and I'm satisfied.